# Custom UIPickerView datasource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have some question about custom `UIPickerView` datasource. I have created a custom class, which is being initiated in one viewController, as I be using this `UIPickerView` in few controllers. So I am just trying to analyze how do I `didSelectRow` result feed back into a property that's being set in the viewController itself?

I have all the delegates being called within the custom class, so now I am little stuck as of how do I pass this `didSelectRow` data to the viewController property.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your viewController an UIPickerViewDelegate, set viewController as a delegate for your picker and implement method `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` in viewController.